# Задача на формулу рекуррентных соотношений (c++)

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

Дано число n (количество элементов) и произвольное вещественное a. Необходимо найти сумму первых n элементов первых членов ряда:

> 1 / a^2 + 3! / a^4 + 5! / a^6 + 7! / a^8 + ...

Решить нужно с обязательным использованием формулы рекуррентных соотношений.

У меня программа получилась такая, но получается какая-то дичь при выполнении программы (числа в ответе слишком большие, когда в при тестовых значениях должно получиться число меньше единицы):

**С++**

```
int n;
double a, sum,c;
pt>>n>>a; //ввод
a= 1.0 / a*a;
sum=a;          
for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
    a=(double)(a*(2*i-2)*(2*i-1))/(a*a);
    sum=sum+a;  
}
pt<<sum;//вывод
```

**Пример:**

*Дано:* n=2, a=9.10;

*Правильный ответ:* 0.012951

**Мой ответ:** 7.0000000 и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваши `a` в числителе и знаменателе имеют разный смысл!

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double a = 9.10;
    int n = 5;

    double b = 1.0/(a*a);
    double sum = b;

    for(int k = 1; k <= n; ++k)
    {
        b = 2*k*(2*k+1)*b/(a*a);
        sum += b;
        cout << "k = " << k << ";   sum = " << sum << endl;
    }
}
```

Если **совсем** плевать на эффективность, но очень хочется чистой рекурсии, то вот она в двойном размере:

```
double term(int k, double a)
{
    if (k == 0) return 1.0/(a*a);
    return term(k-1,a)*2*k*(2*k+1)/(a*a);
}

double sum(int n, double a)
{
    if (n == 0) return term(0,a);
    return sum(n-1,a) + term(n,a);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double a = 9.10;
    int n = 5;

    for(int k = 0; k <= n; ++k)
    {
        cout << "k = " << k << ";   sum = " << sum(k,a) << endl;
    }
}
```

Здесь рекурсивно вычисляется и сумма, и даже каждый член...

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Программа прошла тесты при изменении параметров цикла на: "for(int i=1;i<n;i++)". Сейчас попытаюсь все-таки понять свою ошибку.

Comment: У вас `a` в знаменателе - параметр, но вы и текущий член обозвали той же буквой. В результате при вычислении вместо деления на `a*a`, где `a` - заданная константа, вы делите на квадрат предыдущего члена.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо. Теперь я наконец-то понял где была моя ошибка! Переписал свою программу и она заработала:
 for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
  c=c*(2*i-2)*(2*i-1)/(a*a);
  sum+=c; 
 }